# Trying to put text INFRONT of a document Im about to send to printPreview?

Tags: c#, .net, system.printing

I try to put text on a document Im about to send to PrintPreview using the event **PrintPageEventHandler**. With this code:

```
 System.Drawing.Printing += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(PrintDocument_PrintPage);
```

Then I use the code:

```
void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hawkeye", new Font("Arial", 80, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 0, 0); 
    }
```

When doing that the text ends upp BEHIND the document. I gues its because the event triggers before **System.Printing** is painting the rest of the document on the printing area. Anyone have any suggestion how to do if I want the text infront of the printable document?

Comment: How/where is the rest of the document being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set HasMorePages is false as this is your last/only page. this is something like that

e.HasMorePages=false

Please follow this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages.aspx)

Comment: I did like this instead:  
   `e.HasMorePages = false;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("SampleText", new Font("Arial", 80, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 0, 0);`  But it didnt help!